# Capthca does not dispplay at the time of page load

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I am using google recaptcha . but it is not displaying at the time of pageload . But when i am using ctrl+R is displays. So what should i do to overcome this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['vcRecaptcha']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope ) {

  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.respone1 = '';
  $scope.respone2 = '';
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> 
    <!-- <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&amp;render=explicit" async defer></script> -->
    
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-rechapcha.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(window).load(function () {
  window.location.href=window.location.href
 });
 </script>
 
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    
    <div vc-recaptcha key="'6LdexkAUAAAAAHJjHft19DekOjH0XdNsFjw1mdNm'" ng-model="respone1"></div>
    <!-- <div vc-recaptcha key="'6LdexkAUAAAAAHJjHft19DekOjH0XdNsFjw1mdNm'" ng-model="respone2"></div> -->
    
    <pre>respone1 = {{respone1 | json}}</pre>
    <pre>respone2 = {{respone2 | json}}</pre>
    
  </body>
</html>
```